# Retrieving the status of emails sent via SendGrid

Tags: .net, email, azure, sendgrid

I am creating an application in c# which is using Microsoft Windows Azure cloud platform.

I need to know how come I can track email by using the SendGrid service hosted on azure.The Tracking status May be.

```
4. Track sent emails to determine if they were:
4.1 delivered
4.2 opened
4.3 recipient opt-out
4.4 bounced (with the reason for the bounce)
4.5 time/date sent
4.6 which links in the email were clicked (and time/date they were clicked)
4.7 IP address, if user clicked any links in the email
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: SendGrid is not a Microsoft service, it's another company's service hosted on Azure. Did you check their [documentation](http://sendgrid.com/docs/), especially the section on [Delivery Metrics](http://sendgrid.com/docs/Delivery_Metrics/index.html) ?

Comment: Yes ,I have checked its documentation,but I have no idea how come i can got all the features by code in c#.However all the functionality which I have demanded they are explained in documentation but I need code example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Those events are sent to you via [SendGrid's Event Webhook](http://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Webhooks/event.html). To consume the webhook, you must set up a server that accepts POST requests, and processes the data in those POST requests.

This [article explains webhooks](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/576278/Webhooks-webhook-URLs-and-a-sample-implementation) and and goes on to discuss how to create [REST Services in C#](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/275279/Developing-WCF-Restful-Services-with-GET-and-POST), which you'll need to consume the webhook.

**Edit**: This [Github Project](https://github.com/paully21/SendGridWebHookExample) acts as a great example of how to use SendGrid's Event Webhook with C#.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to use our webhooks, you can try:

Web API:

http://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Web_API/Statistics/index.html http://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Web_API/Statistics/statistics_advanced.html

Here is some example code:

http://sendgrid.com/blog/using-sendgrid-with-visual-studio-2013-preview-for-windows-8-1-development

Comment: With the caveat to this being, that you can only track aggregate data– not data on an individual email basis.