# How to get event notifications in SendGrid using ASP.NET

Tags: sendgrid, webhooks

I m facing same problem in Event Notification Implementation as SendGrid doesn't provide any asp.net documentation or sample. I want to insert event notification in DB.

Kindly let me know if you found something.

Thanks, 
Sagar

Answer (score 1):

There's a github project which acts as a good example on [how to consume SendGrid's Event Webhook with ASP.NET](https://github.com/paully21/SendGridWebHookExample).

[This answer to a previous question goes into slightly more depth](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22231987/648494).

Comment: best and Super easy to use your solution. took me less than 1 hour to deploy whole Send grid webhook app to production environment.